# Is it possible to select meshes which are not attached to the larger mesh object

Tags: edit-mode

I have extracted a 3d satellite image of a city to a .rdc file using renderdoc and imported it into Blender then selected ALL and joined to a single mesh (ctrl J).
I have 'cleaned' it up in edit mode using the lasso tool and then delete vertices.  There are still many small objects which are 'floating in space' (not attached to the main object (see image below with one such selected with the lasso). Is it possible to select ONLY those small objects for deletion? I have manually removed many but there are still some which I cannot 'isolate' and 'lasso' as they are too close to the main object to be able to select with the lasso without also selecting part of the main object[image]n object.
Maybe this could be done BEFORE joining all meshes?

The following are the object view and edit view of the (3d satellite image) model
[image]

[image]

Comment: why don't you just select one vertex of the main object, press ctrl-L and hide them? then you can remove the small ones. Or if you wanna delete all of them, after press ctrl-L you can press ctrl-I (i am not sure whether it's ctrl-i because i am working on a mac, but i mean invert selection [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR633.png) and delete them

Comment: does hovering over the object and pressing `L` to select it not work?

Comment: yes, i think that works too

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions. However They do not seem to work. I selected one vertex but I only know how to hide using the 'scene collection' panel and there is only one mesh displayed and so hiding it hides everything. Is there another 'hide' function? And hovering over one and pressing L only selects a few virtices unless it is a simple mesh eg a triangle. Also that requires finding all the 'floating' meshes.

Comment: If you go to FACE select mode before pressing L it will only select polygons, stray vertices and edges won't be selected. So the workflow is Select object > TAB into edit mode, 3 to go to face select, press L while hovering over a face, 1 to go to vertex select mode, CTRL + i to invert selection, X to delete > vertices

Comment: Thanks gorgious.  I did that and ended up deleting all but one small set of vertexes. I am now assuming that you mean that I should hover over of the face of one of the 'floating' meshes (not attached to the main object)? If so then I can't do that in face mode as I can't find where they are. Maybe it's not worth the effort?

Answer (score 1):

If you know you have only one big main object and a lot of floating ones, you can separate by loose parts.

- select your main object and go into edit mode
- select all geometry
- right-click and `Separate > By Loose Parts`
- go back to object mode
- select your main object, invert selection and delete

Comment: Since he wants to delete all smaller parts, why bother to separate them all into single objects and have a hell of a lot new objects there (if there are many)? Just select the main mesh in _Edit Mode_, invert selection and delete the other parts.

Comment: Oh right, way simpler!

Comment: Hi Gordon. Is your method going to work with a single mesh? If so what is the keyboard command to Invert? Also if I only have one mesh how do I select a particular object?   Thanks taiyo  I am at present in the middle or using your method however with a huge number of vertices, faces (over300,000)  etc it has been now running for over 10 minutes and not completed yet.

Comment: Wow, this should really not take so long. Sure, depends on the machine but for example i have 3 million faces and 300 floating objects joined/separated in 1-2 seconds. Invert shortcut is Ctrl+I (Cmd+I) or you do `Select > Invert` in the header menu (top left).

Comment: My PC config contains an i7 9700K cpu and 8Gb ram (only).  I tried your method on a very simple blender project consisting 3 separate meshes combined into one (ctrl j) and it separated them instantly. Then tried on a more simple but still complex 3d satellite image and after a couple of minutes of not finishing I killed the process.  Regarding using Invert I don't know how to select "the main mesh" in edit mode. I will add an image of the model above Blender file far too large to upload.

Comment: Seems to be something with the model, can you share the .blend file? Regarding selecting: go to edit mode and select one (or some) vertex/edge/face of the main mesh.  Then hold the arrow up key. This is the same as `Select > Select More/Less > More` multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for your help taiyo.  I tried slecting first a vertex and then a face and holding down the uparrow key but it displayed 'no more keyframes to jump to in this direction'. which looks like its trying to access animation?  I can't upload my blender file here as it is over 70Gb in size. I could upload it to 'mega' (cloud) and give you the link but maybe its not worth the effort. I tried

Comment: Oh 70 Gb, ok... Regarding up arrow, sry i have the mode `Industry compatible` (you can change that in `Edit > Preferences > Keymap`). If you use `Blender/Blender 27x` mode, its `Ctrl Numpad +` (it shows you the shortcuts when you hover over menu entries).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147145/discussion-between-john-arnold-and-taiyo).